# Inside shadow dom ag-grid column filter key events like escape and tab keys are not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid, shadow-dom

I have placed entire ag-grid in shadow dom. I am using default column filters. When I opened the filter and try to close it by using escape key it is not closing.

I think ag-grid key events might not getting added to filter.
[ag-grid column filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vewjc.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:-

```
defaultColDef: {
    suppressKeyboardEvent: (params) => {
            if (params?.event?.key === "Escape") {
                                return true;  // false
                            };
        
        }
}
```